# Custom control bindable Property not getting hit when set from a view

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, bindableproperty

I've created a control and it has a bindable property, but when I try to set its value, it does not set, when I check its setter, it's not getting hit while debugging, not sure what am I doing wrong.

```
public decimal MetricValue
        {
            get => (decimal)GetValue(MetricValueProperty);
            set => SetValue(MetricValueProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty MetricValueProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(
                propertyName: nameof(MetricValue),
                returnType: typeof(decimal),
                declaringType: typeof(HeightSelection),
                defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
                propertyChanged: MetricValuePropertyChanged);
```

I also have a propertychanged, which is not getting raised

```
 <controls:customControl
                                        CurrentSystemOfMeasure="{Binding CurrentSystemOfMeasure}"
                                        MetricValue="{Binding CurrentHeight}"
                                        TextAlignment="Start"
                                        OnHeightSelectedCommand="{Binding HeightSelectionCommand}"
                                        IsValid="True" />
```

any inputs would be helpful

Comment: May I know the relevant code of the specific location of the setter that you failed to hit during debugging?

Comment: @HongxinSui-MSFT Added reference to binding in the view where the control is being consumed and now it is working, not sure why is it not working without the reference, what do you think might be wrong here?

Comment: Yes. That could mean the binding should be set in the xaml view to enable the custom control to call the binding property and make the program run normally.

Comment: @HongxinSui-MSFT I did set the binding from the xaml view, but it needed a reference to the instance of the ViewModel set as bindingcontext which holds the Value to be binded, which is strange, since other views in that page do not require a reference

Comment: May I know your xaml view? That can make me help you better.

Answer (score 0):

have you set  context in the xaml view?

Here my way:

```
 public static readonly BindableProperty CancelButtonVisibleAvailableProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: "CancelButtonVisible",
        returnType: typeof(bool),
        declaringType: typeof(SelphiDetailPhotosView),
        defaultValue: true);

    public bool CancelButtonVisible
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(CancelButtonVisibleAvailableProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CancelButtonVisibleAvailableProperty, value); }
    }
```

ContentView needs to have a x:name to set the context in the property IsVisible in your case you need to set the context in Text Property of label to show decimal value

I have set the context making reference to my custom view **selphiDetailPhotosView**

```
   <Button IsVisible="{Binding Source={x:Reference selphiDetailPhotosView}, Path=CancelButtonVisible}"
                        Margin="27,0,27,18"
                        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource PlatinumColor}"
                        Command="{Binding CancelCommand}"
                        Text="Cancelar"
                        TextColor="White"
                        TextTransform="None" />



<ContentView
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
x:Class="confia.Views.Views.OnBoardingAndLivenessSharedViews.SelphiDetailPhotosView"
   xmlns:svg="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms"
xmlns:transformation="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Transformations;assembly=FFImageLoading.Transformations"
xmlns:views="clr-namespace:confia.Views.Views"
  xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:confia.Views.Converters"
x:Name="selphiDetailPhotosView"
>
```

Finally call your customcontrol in your ContentPage and bind with your ViewModel

<customControl:SelphiDetailPhotosView CancelButtonVisible="{Binding CanCancel}"/>

Comment: Yes, I've set the bindingcontext to self if that's what you meant?, but i'm not even trying to set the view right now, i'm just trying to pass a value from a view to my customcontrol and that's not happening

Answer (score 0):

I have replicated your scenario and this work for me.

CodeBehind Custom Control

```
 public partial class CustomControl : ContentView
{
    public CustomControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty MetricValueProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
       propertyName: nameof(MetricValue),
       returnType: typeof(decimal),
       declaringType: typeof(CustomControl),
       defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
       defaultValue: 0m);

    public decimal MetricValue
    {
        get { return (decimal)this.GetValue(MetricValueProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(MetricValueProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

CustomControl Xaml

```
<ContentView
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
x:Class="ferreplace.Views.Controls.CustomControl"
x:Name="this"
>
<ContentView.Content>
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" >
        <Label Text="Metric Value" FontSize="40"/>
        <Label FontSize="20" Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference  this}, Path=MetricValue}" ></Label>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView.Content>
```

ContenPage to call Custom control

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ferreplace.Views.Controls"
             x:Class="ferreplace.MainPage">
 <StackLayout>
      <controls:CustomControl MetricValue="{Binding MetricValueBinding}"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

ViewModel

```
 public class MainPageViewModel: BindableBase, IInitializeAsync
{

    private decimal _metricValueBinding;
    public decimal MetricValueBinding
    {
        get
        {
            return _metricValueBinding;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _metricValueBinding, value);
        }
    }

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
    }

    public async Task InitializeAsync(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        MetricValueBinding = 30m;
    }
}
```

[Decimal Binding Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCxQO.jpg)
Maybe you forgot default value in bindable property creation

Comment: Added reference to binding in the view where the control is being consumed and now it is working, not sure why is it not working without the reference